# Fade out elements on page without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, web

I would like to fade out some elements on my page with javascript but without jquery. How should I do this onclick?

Comment: I'd add a class to the element and use a CSS transition. But what have _you_ tried?

Comment: Why avoiding jQuery, out of interest?

Comment: @freejosh: That would require CSS3

Comment: @Amberlamps you're talking about fading content in today's world - CSS3 is very likely on the table.

Comment: Fade in and fade out in pure javascript: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/fade-in-and-fade-out-in-pure-javascript

Comment: @freejosh I haven't looked much into changing opacity with CSS, but I thought it could be done relatively simply with JS

Comment: @AdrianWragg I don't want to use the large jQuery file for a simple fading effect.

Comment: @David Yep, it is relatively simple in JS (as seen in the answers). But your question didn't provide any use-cases or constraints so for all we know you could only be interested in iOS and Android - in which case a CSS transition is the simplest and most performant answer.

Comment: @freejosh Actually yes, the page in developing is primarily for mobile devices. Would you recommend using keyframes in CSS?

Comment: @David No, you don't need keyframes for this. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After our small discussion in the comments of your question you mentioned you were primarily targeting mobile devices. [CSS transition](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions), therefore, might be your best option as it's supported by all versions of iOS and Android and doesn't perform any expensive JavaScript loops.

[Here's a fiddle of a working minimal implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/xyFTK/).

HTML:

```html
<a href="#" id="doFade">fade</a>
<div id="toFade">...</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#toFade {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
    opacity: 1;
}

#toFade.faded {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('doFade').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('toFade').className += 'faded';
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var s = document.getElementById('thing').style;
s.opacity = 1;
(function fade(){(s.opacity-=.1)<0?s.display="none":setTimeout(fade,40)})();
```

taken from http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: I love the conciseness of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only targeting browsers that support CSS3 fade options, go for CSS3, but if not you'll want something like:

```
function addEvent(obj,event,func)
{
    if(typeof func !== 'function')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(typeof obj.addEventListener == 'function' || typeof obj.addEventListener == 'object')
    {
        return obj.addEventListener(event.replace(/^on/,''), func, false);
    }
    else if(typeof obj.attachEvent == 'function' || typeof obj.attachEvent == 'object')
    {
        return obj.attachEvent(event,func);
    }
}
addEvent(elem,'onclick',function(e) {
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    target.style.opacity = 1;
    var fadeOutInt = setInterval(function() {
        target.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        if(target.style.opacity <= 0) clearInterval(fadeOutInt);
    },50);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmokeyPHP/sHvtd/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'd make your own fadeOut function?

```
function fade(element, speed) {
    var op = 1,
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            if (op <= 0.1){
                clearInterval(timer);
                element.style.display = 'none';
            }
            element.style.opacity = op;
            element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
            op -= op * 0.1;
        }, speed);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KNszM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.fade{

opacity: 0;

}
```

JavaScript

```
var myEle=document.getElementById("myID");
myEle.className += " fade"; //to fadeIn
myEle.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)fade(?!\S)/ , '' ) //to fadeOut
```